# Step in proof of Dirichlet Series Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading [this proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet_Series_Convergence_Lemma), and am wondering about the justification of the step labeled "telescoping the series on the right."

$$\sum_{n=m}^{N-1} |(n+1)^{-s}-n^{-s}| \le |N^{-s}-m^{-s}|$$
where $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

Why are you allowed to do this when there are absolute value signs?

Comment: I don't know where in the proof you linked is the expression above, but in what you wrote everything's positive for any $\;s\in\Bbb R\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Apologies, $s$ is complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point, which I think the author of ProofWiki proof has missed. When $\operatorname{Re} s>0$, we have

$$\begin{split}
\left|\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}}-\frac{1}{n^s}\right| & =\left|\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{s}{x^{s+1}}\,dx\right| \\ & \leq |s| \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{\operatorname{Re} s +1}} \\ &=\frac{|s|}{\operatorname{Re} s }\left(\frac{1}{n^{\operatorname{Re} s }}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\operatorname{Re} s }}\right)
\end{split}$$

Which leads to telescoping, but with the extra constant factor in front.

As seen in [Uniform convergence of Dirichlet series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586941/), answer by Josué Tonelli-Cueto.